# How to remove remaining stacks from recursive method

Tags: ruby, recursion, stack

I wrote a Sudoku solver using a recursive method. It looks something like this:

```
def solve(index = @board.key("-"), board_so_far = @board)
  if !board_so_far.has_value?("-")
    @solution = board_so_far
    return true
  elsif available_nums_to_place(index, board_so_far).any?
    available_nums_to_place(index, board_so_far).each do |num|
      board_so_far[index] = num
      solve(board_so_far.key("-"), Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(board_so_far)))
    end
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

It will save the solution in `@solution` once a solution is found. When this happens, I would like to stop all remaining recursions. Right now, the `solve` method goes on about twice as long as it needs to after already having found the solution by interpreting the other stacks. How can I kill the rest of the stacks? I used `break` in place of my `return`'s and the interpreter throws a

> Invalid break runner.rb: compile error (SyntaxError)

error.

## UPDATE 1

Below is the full code that I hope is clear enough without needing further explanation.

```
class Sudoku

  def initialize(board_string)
    @board = to_hash(board_string)
    @solution = {}
  end

private

  def to_hash(board_string)
    output_hash = {}
    board_array = board_string.split("")
    board_array.each_with_index do |char,i|
      char == "-" ? output_hash[i] = "-" : output_hash[i] = char.to_i
    end
    output_hash
  end

  def row_number(index)
    row_number = index/9
  end

  def column_number(index)
    column_number = index % 9
  end

  def indices_of_row(index)
    starting_index = row_number(index) * 9
    row_indices = (starting_index...starting_index + 9).to_a
    row_indices.delete(index)
    row_indices
  end

  def indices_of_column(index)
    column_indices = 0.upto(8).map { |row| row * 9 + column_number(index) }
    column_indices.delete(index)
    column_indices
  end

  def grid_coords(index)
    [row_number(index) / 3, column_number(index) / 3]
  end

  def top_left_corner_index(coords)
    coords[1] * 3 + coords[0] * 27
  end

  def indices_of_grid(index)
    i = top_left_corner_index(grid_coords(index))
    position_adjustment = [0,1,2,9,10,11,18,19,20]
    indices_of_grid = position_adjustment.map { |num| num + i }
    indices_of_grid.delete(index)
    indices_of_grid
  end

  def available_nums(indices, board)
    value_array = indices.map { |index| board[index] }
    complete = (1..9).to_a
    unplaced_nums = complete - value_array
  end

  def available_nums_to_place(index, board)
    row_values = available_nums( indices_of_row(index), board )
    column_values = available_nums( indices_of_column(index), board )
    grid_values = available_nums( indices_of_grid(index), board )
  end

public

  def solve(index = @board.key("-"), board_so_far = @board)

    if !board_so_far.has_value?("-")
      @solution = board_so_far
      return true
    elsif available_nums_to_place(index, board_so_far).any?
      available_nums_to_place(index, board_so_far).each do |num|
        board_so_far[index] = num
        solve(board_so_far.key("-"), Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(board_so_far)))
      end
    else
      return false
    end
  end

  # Returns a string representing the current state of the board
  def to_s
    puts "+-----------------------+"
    puts "|        SUDOKU!        |"
    puts "+-----------------------+"
    three_rows = @solution.values.each_slice(27).map { |rows| rows }
    three_rows.each do |three_rows|
      three_rows.each_slice(9) do |row|
        printf("| %s %s %s | %s %s %s | %s %s %s |\n", row[0], row[1], row[2],  row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8] )
      end
      puts "|-----------------------|\n"
    end
  end
end

sudoku_strings = File.read('sudoku_puzzles.txt')
sudoku_arrays = sudoku_strings.split("\n")

sudokus_to_solve = sudoku_arrays.take(1)

sudokus = sudokus_to_solve.map do |unsolved_board|
  Sudoku.new(unsolved_board)
end

sudokus.each do |sudoku|
  sudoku.solve
  sudoku.to_s
end
```

Comment: You have many methods/variables unexplained. That makes your question answerable by guess at best.

Comment: @sawa, welcome back!

Comment: @CarySwoveland I will participate only occasionally. I will not spend too much time on this.

Comment: Sure, adding it now, I just didn't want to add any extraneous and confusing code since I thought the question was generic enough.

Comment: Can you provide `sudoku_arrays` containing one test problem?

Comment: Yes, it was just so I can quickly test that it can solve at least one puzzle. I have solved up to 12 puzzles with this.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
solve(board_so_far.key("-"), Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(board_so_far)))
```

to

```
if solve(board_so_far.key("-"), Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(board_so_far)))
  return true
end
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I did this and after 3 recursions the interpreter stopped without finding the solution.